# JavaFX WebView does not load page

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-8, javafx-webview

I am trying to open "engine.load("https://login.microsoftonline.com");" in JavaFX WebView.

When using **jdk1.8.0_161** the page is loaded. When using **jdk1.8.0_181** the page does not load. It displays empty window and does not return any error:
    engine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty() is null.

Do you have any idea what might have changed in new version updates of Java? I tested on Java 10 latest release and the page is also not loaded.
This code works with JDK8.161 and JDK9.0.4 but does not work with JDK8.181 and JDK10.0.2

Here is the source code of the sample app I have created:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebErrorEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class LoginApplicationWindow {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(620, 440);
        final JFXPanel fxpanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxpanel);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WebEngine engine;               
                WebView wv = new WebView();
                engine = wv.getEngine();
                engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                 // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
                TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }};

                // Install the all-trusting trust manager
                SSLContext sc;
                try {
                    sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                // Create all-trusting host name verifier
                HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                // Install the all-trusting host verifier
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);

                engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
                      public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                          Document doc = engine.getDocument();
                          // operations on dom occur here.
                          System.out.println(engine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty());
                          System.out.print("load finished " + doc.getBaseURI());
                        }
                      }
                });


                engine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WebEvent<String> event) {
                        System.out.print("setOnAlert " + event.getData());
                    }
                });

                engine.setOnError(new EventHandler<WebErrorEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WebErrorEvent event) {
                        System.out.print("onError " + event.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                engine.setConfirmHandler(new Callback<String, Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(String param) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.print("setConfirmHandler " + param);
                        return null;
                    }
                });


                fxpanel.setScene(new Scene(wv));
                engine.load("https://login.microsoftonline.com");
                //engine.load("https://facebook.com");

            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [A comment on a related question's answer on how to trust all certificates on SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https#comment12218559_4837230) notes that the [`X509TrustManager` `getAcceptedIssuers()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html#getAcceptedIssuers()) requires a non-null array to be returned. You return `null` rather than an empty array. Maybe this specification was not enforced initially but sometime between those Java versions it became enforced. Try changing this.

Comment: Well, this is not the problem for sure. I tried returning an empty array and the result is the same. No page is displayed.. I don't get an SSL error. I don't get any error, only empy page.. this is the url that the screen is last redirected to:

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=4345a7b9-9a63-4910-a426-35363201d503&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dpy_xaopHcEgk43cRwZRYYazvRPVVbN-ONslTeKUDC1qDhzC8nXkFsaz8hSygcRph1pAxr2BgnjyRHbLYaXqAepdY1lv2hXKxJj4vzN7hlCS7kuyO74j_3AzJeQvlODpW&nonce=636722871614920197.Mzk3NjMxYTMtZjE5YS00MWVkLTk3OGMtNjIxM2VjMmY1ZDg1ZDJkYzA3OGEtMjI4Zi00NWM1LTlkNDQtOGI1Zjc1NWJiZGY1&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.office.com%2f&ui_locales=en-US&mkt=en-US

Comment: I've tested your code in each of those four JDKs to confirm that it is indeed a JDK issue rather than a system issue. I have no idea why this issue occurs in some JDKs and not others. Bizarre.

Comment: Compare the java.security files in the JRE/lib/security folders. I have the feeling that either the order of the security.providers have been changed (once we got this surprise) or some SSL related settings has been changed.

Comment: @m4gic I tried replacing the security folder of JRE181 with the security folder from JRE161(there were really a few differences in the files) but it didn't work. The result was the same so I guess the problem is not with the security folders

Comment: Please check that your configuration is a [supported JavaFX configuration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html), this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) maybe more accurate

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that ANY network problem (DNS/connection) can cause the error and the load will not throw any proper exception.
The good news is that if you replace the .load(url) call, at least you will see the problems in the log.

On replacing I mean that load the site separately to a String

```
private static String getData(String address) throws Exception {
    URL page = new URL(address);
    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) page.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    try (InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(
            (InputStream) conn.getContent())) {
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        do {
            line = buff.readLine();
            text.append(line + "\n");
        } while (line != null);
        return text.toString();
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

And replace the .load:

```
    //engine.load("https://login.microsoftonline.com");
    engine.loadContent(getData("https://login.microsoftonline.com"));
```

Of course, the exception should be catched and logged properly.
(The funny thing is that the referenced resources (images/js/css whatever files) will be loaded well in this way too.)

Comment: So this is not an SSL issue. I tried to download the content as a String and I got it. But when I try to place it in the webview with loadContent then I got the empty screen. If I set any other HTML valid string in loadContent it is loaded...

Comment: Hm I have not tested the solution with your URL. I did it at home and it seems this site uses Oauth2 and maybe frames too, either of them, or maybe the javascript is the reason why it does not work (I got a null only). [here](http://blog.disy.net/swing-browser-integration/) you can read a comparison about the available browsers for java, maybe you should switch to another implementation. Another option is to do the oauth2 manually, but that would be too painful I think.